# How to select value from search drop down

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to select value from this type of drop down.

// select value from dropdown

```
 Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("select2-operative_id-container"))); 
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Administrator");
```

and

Try above both method but not able to select value.

Please consider below image for better Understanding.
[click this Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hULN2.png)

For drop down value I am not able to select Xpath.

Comment: Can you share you html? I guessing is not a `<selector>` tag in the source so then the `new Select()` wont work.

Comment: Kindly share html also.

Comment: You need to show HTML of the dropdown

Comment: is it showing dropdown element in `<li>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    This is select drop down.

    Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("put here xpath")));
    dropdown.selectByValue("A");

    For bootstrap dropdown
# you have to first click on the arrow icon(v) of the drop down.
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("put here xpath of the v icon")).click();
# Then find the xpath of the value which you have to select from drop down and then apply click operation on it.
driver.findElement(By.xpath("put here xpath of the value within drop down")).click();
```

Comment: Want to know, for example, in amazon i enter "app" search input, i will get the search suggestions like apple watch, apple watchband, apple phone etc.... If i want to click on 4th suggestion then how can i achieve it. Can someone give me the xpath for that? Please use amazon site as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the dropdown find the value and select your chosen option.

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("select2-operative_id-container")));

dropdown.selectByValue("Administrator");
```

or another method than should work is to send keys to select the option.

```
WebElement dropdown = new WebElement(driver.findElement(By.id("select2-operative_id-container")));
dropdown.sendKeys("Administrator");
```

Comment: Can you send some logs or some information on the error. A screenshot of the webelement attributes would help also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SelectByValue method.

Add the value name as string as below.

```
Select oSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("select2-operative_id-container")));
oSelect.selectByValue(<your value>);
```